# Angular how to show page url of the component lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I have an application where i have multiple components loading in a lazy loading manner using ngx-infinite-scroll

Till now i am able to get the components and able to lazy load

You can see the running project here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yixdus

But unfortunately i am unable to figure out how to implement the url thing

How to show url of the specific component while scrolling down??

the demo which i need to make it similar is given in this url - http://scrollsample.appspot.com

As you can see in the above url that when we scroll down our url changes accordingly

Please help !!

Comment: u can achieve by using offset and limit.
like when by default you need to send offset 0 and limit 50 and by using offset you need to fetch 50 records on basis of offset and limit. when hitting service again and again you need to increase offset like 0, 50, 100, 150 and so on and will fetch next records and cancate with current records from front-end side
by using this approach u dont need to change the url.

Comment: how it will help in showing/changing the url in the address bar

Comment: @FarhatZaman and if you reload the page, you lose everything. Not a good idea at all.

Comment: @user4965201 have you seen [fragments](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) ?

Comment: @FarhatZaman but if we have the page number param we wont lose the state